# Using ReactJS with PHP and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

Hey Guys so I just started learning ReactJS and I love it a lot,
yet I have never seen anyone using it with PHP it seems like everyone uses Node instead, the question is can I even use PHP and Laravel with it? cheers.

Comment: SO is about solving coding errors...

Comment: A React app is usually a single page app. Backend communication happens using AJAX, which means most of the time you're going to make API requests like for instance `api.php?action=getuserinfo&userid=1` and send back JSON. Whether you use PHP or node.js or some other backend language is up to you, but Laravel is out of the picture here.

Comment: I literally seen questions like mine many times here, I didn't know it wasn't acceptable here!

Comment: @JohnSanchez People keep asking off-topic questions unfortunately, and other people keep answering them. That's why I posted my answer as a comment.

Comment: React is simply what the user sees, i.e the front-end. Laravel is the backend, where you retrieve, store, process data from databases. To get started with using laravel as an API, check out [dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api). Then you use react with ajax to interact with your laravel backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, absolutely! The backend does not matter since React is just a view layer (very controversial statement, but for the same of simplicity).

As long as you expose the endpoints, consume it and then, in turn, provide React (or Redux) with the data, it doesn't matter which framework you use it with.

The reason why people usually use Node.js is because of **isomorphism**: you write the backend and the frontend in the same language so you don't get confused.

Comment: What about the difference between the Front or the Backend rendering tho, whats the difference?

Comment: So, frontend rendering means that the frontend framework (React) renders the HTML based on the data provided. In backend rendering, the server provides you with an already-rendered page which is just displayed in the web browser to be displayed.

Comment: So the data provided by the framework MUST be static? Can't I like read data from the DB with it? 

sorry if this is kinda stupid.

Comment: Framework? Which framework? Node.js? PHP? React?

Comment: Oh I meant React sorry.

Comment: Hi ! As @weirdpanda pointed out React is a front-end framework. So it is capable of displaying the data on the web page based on your instructions. Now, this data could be static or dynamic. In case it is dynamic, you will be contacting the server/database to get this data and give it to the react layer so that it can be displayed on the browser. I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can change out the Vue.js scaffolding in a laravel 5.5 project using

> php artisan preset react

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend

Would have simply commented this but not enough Rep yet! // yolo

Comment: God bless, thanks mate